Hiragana mystifying words and grammar (possibly any sound changes)
The hiragana in this song is throwing me way off... These lines are extremely mysterious...

ゆみよにまひて
あなしあふれり
(おもてをはがして)しいまうや

Well, I reasoned that the ゆみ in ゆみよにまひて was a kagura bow although I earlier suspected that it was a sound changed term (like 寝見(いみ;from 夢(いめ) to ゆみ) because the ゆみ would be personified and ゆゆく seems to be sound changed from perhaps 行(ゆ)く(き?)行(ゆ)く but the line still is mysterious, and I don't know what よにまひて stands for (世に迷ひて? よ(愛情)に舞ひて?). I do not know what the し is doing there if not playing the role of emphasis as あな seems to be merely an interjection, and しいまう doesn't even seem to be a real word... It seems to be composed of some root, む and repetitive/continuous う/ふ. Are the lines just incomprehensible?
Lyrics:
おもてはがればあなしあふれり かれらはゆゆく よみじをゆゆく
葬送
遂げぬ想いが列を成し嘆きを曳いて消える
ゆみよにまひて　よみじをゆゆく
死神楽
姫らの啜り泣き囃子にして舞いくるり
おもてはがれば　あなしあふれり
かれらはゆゆく　よみじをゆゆく
永久の別れ　彼の人はもう居ない
叶わぬ想いを舞に乗せ今宵もまた空ヽ(からから)獅子は舞う
傍に居るだけでも
死花花閃ヽ舞い散らせ言葉も亡く姫らは泣き崩る
想い絶てずに
夢見逢瀬
想いは募り募りて終いを手繰り寄せ
ししのおもては　よみじのくさび
ぬきはなたれば　あなしあふれり
あはれなひめは　いつかちがひて
おもてをはがしてしいまうや
あまりに恋し
せめてもう一目だけでも
叶わぬ想いに身を裂いて　今宵もまた姫らの涙雨
傍に居るだけでは
黄泉の理はいと昏し　どれだけ想い焦がれ求めても
生きては会えぬ
貴方と添い遂ぐ為ならば妾の命も惜しくはないのです
だから貴方のお側に
死に別れた愛しき人にまた逢わんと憐れな姫がまたひとり
黄泉路を逝往く

I think overall, your guesses are correct and those words are only understandable very vaguely. ゆゆく and しいまう should be certainly ゆく and しまう.

Yeah, I thought as much (that it was a stylized shimau)... I think this song may use poetic license (の涙雨 instead of への涙雨 is a bit unusual to take with the given meanings)

As for あなし, my take would be "あな made archaic-adjective-like by adding し". Almost purely by context, あなしあふれり just means something like full of sadness (when the mask fell off).  I don't think they are really thought out grammatically.

The comment section of this Piapro page has the kanji version provided by the author:

夢見夜に舞いて黄泉路を逝往く
面剥がれば　あな死溢れり
彼等は逝往く　黄泉路を逝往く
獅子の面は黄泉路の楔
抜き放たればあな死溢れり
憐れな姫はいつか狂いて
面を剥がしてしいまうや


ゆみよにまひて
→ 夢見夜に舞いて
→ 夢見(の)夜に舞って (dancing in the dreaming night)
あなしあふれり
→ あな死溢れり
→ ああ、死が溢れ(てしまっ)た (oh, death has overflowed)
(Note: No one has removed their mask (yet), so it may be better to ignore the literal meaning and translate this as "death will overflow" to make it fit the context.)
おもてをはがしてしいまうや
→ 面を剥がして仕(い)舞うや
→ 面を剥がしてしまうよ (she will end up removing her mask)

(I think it's impossible even for native speakers to completely predict the words from these hiragana. In particular, 夢見夜 and 逝往く are probably made-up words. It was impossible for me to read ちがひて as "going mad", too.)
